# How do I change a binary string to an alphanumeric string in Java?

Tags: java

After trying every answer on this topic I could find (and searching for almost a full day), I've been unable to successfully convert binary data in string format (variable a) to an alphanumeric string. My question is "What am I doing wrong?"

Ultimately I want this to print out a human readable string, such as "Hello There", which would be the integer 87521618088882520788922981 (input will be changed to long.)

```
int input = 256;
    int maxInt = 10000;
    String result = "";
    String o;
    String a = "";
    String stringByte;
    char c;
    int pos;
     while (input <= maxInt){
         System.out.println("Input:          " + input);
         o = Integer.toBinaryString(input);
         System.out.println("Binary String:  " + o);
         System.out.println("Remainder:      " + o.length() % 8);
         if (((o.length() % 8) == 0) && (o != "0")){
             //is a multiple
            a = o;
        }else{
            a = o;
            while ((a.length() % 8 != 0)){
                a = "0" + a;
            }
         }
         //divide into bytes
         System.out.println("Zero-putter:    " + a);
         int numBytes = a.length()/8;
         pos = 1;
         System.out.println("Bytes Received: " + numBytes);
             byte[] bytes = a.getBytes();
             String str = new String(bytes);
         System.out.println("Character:      " + str);
         System.out.println("-----------------------------");
         input++;
         try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }



     }
```

Answers I've tried:
- [Binary to text in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java)
- [Convert binary string to ascii text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453017/convert-binary-string-to-ascii-text)
- [Parsing a string of binary into text/characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222526/parsing-a-string-of-binary-into-text-characters)
- [How to convert efficiently binary string to binary byte array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395994/how-to-convert-efficiently-binary-string-to-binary-byte-array-in-java)
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/247956-convert-binary-data-to-text/
- [How do I convert a large binary String to byte array java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664078/how-do-i-convert-a-large-binary-string-to-byte-array-java)
- [How do I convert a large binary String to byte array java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664078/how-do-i-convert-a-large-binary-string-to-byte-array-java)

Comment: It would be helpful to list "every answer on this topic" you've tried so you don't receive duplicate answer you claim didn't work for you.

Comment: Alphanumeric? Do you mean a decimal string? Also, separating your logic from the Scanner/input/output would make it easier to test.

Comment: Give an example of what this should print.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard The scanner is declared but is never used. that is a remnant from an iteration when I tried to put a "stop the loop" command in.

Comment: If it isn't relevant, you should remove it from the question...

Comment: Show clear sample of your input and expected output. It's unclear what your're asking and what's the purpose.

Comment: binary string to hex string: Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(input, 2), 16)

Comment: this in unclear:  "Hello There", which would be the integer 87521618088882520788922981. How an ARRAY of characters (or numbers) colud be converted in ONE single number?

Comment: @MatteoRubini the idea is as the number counts up, it is seperated into groups of 8 bits. these bits are then converted to alphanumeric charaters, and put in a string.

Comment: an 8bit number is in range of (255-0). if u concatenate them, u can't split again because you don't know how long is any number. f.e. if i concatenate 124;45;22;1;23 i get 1244522123 and is impossible to know how to split again

Comment: @MatteoRubini the number is converted to binary first, and then groups of 8 bits. As in ASCII alphanumeric characters are ID's 33 - 122, each group of 8 bits should (at some point) return a  letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try BigInteger to convert byte array to limitless number.

1- convert your String in array of characters

```
char[] chars = myString.getBytes();
```

2- convert your array of characters in array of bytes ( byte b = (byte)c where c is character )

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[chars.length];
for(int i=0; i<bytes.length;i++){
  bytes[i] = (byte)chars[i];
}
```

3- use BigInteger

```
BigInteger myData = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

4- display as string

```
myData.toString();
```